# I want to show the data received in my socket event into ajax datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, datatables

I am using socket to receive the json data from my backend. I am receiving the data in the DATA variable and want to iterate it into the ajax datatable. Here is my code.

`

```
 socket.on('getinvoices', (data) => {

                var table = $('#table1').DataTable( {
                   
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        order: false,
                  ajax: {
                    url : "https://testdma.tech-east.com.pk/dma/invoices/getAllInvoices",
                    dataSrc: "doc",
                    order: [[0]], 
                  },
                  columns: [
                    { data: 'recipientName' },
                    { data: 'recipientAddress' },
                    { data: 'recipientPhoneNumber' },
                    { data: 'recipientEmail' },
                    { data: 'services[/ ].serviceName' },
                    { data: 'services[/ ].servicePrice' },
                    {
                    data: null,
                    className: "dt-center editor-delete",
                    orderable: true,
                    "mRender" : function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return '<button class="btn viewbtn" value=' +data._id +'>Edit</button>';
                    }
                },   
                {
                    data: null,
                    className: "dt-center editor-delete",
                    orderable: true,
                    "mRender" : function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return '<button class="btn viewbtn2" value=' +data._id +'>Print Invoice</button>';
                    }
                }          

                  ],
                });
```

The data variable on in the socket is where I am receiving my data into.

I tried putting the DATA instead of URL into the ajax datatable but it didnt worked.Kindly guide me how can i populate table with that data

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure to populate a jQuery DataTable with data from a socket event, you can use the `ajax.reload()` method to update the table's data. Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
// Define the table
var table = $('#table1').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
  ],
  order: false,
  columns: [
    { data: 'recipientName' },
    { data: 'recipientAddress' },
    { data: 'recipientPhoneNumber' },
    { data: 'recipientEmail' },
    { data: 'services[/ ].serviceName' },
    { data: 'services[/ ].servicePrice' },
    {
      data: null,
      className: "dt-center editor-delete",
      orderable: true,
      "mRender" : function ( data, type, row ) {
          return '<button class="btn viewbtn" value=' +data._id +'>Edit</button>';
      }
    },   
    {
      data: null,
      className: "dt-center editor-delete",
      orderable: true,
      "mRender" : function ( data, type, row ) {
          return '<button class="btn viewbtn2" value=' +data._id +'>Print Invoice</button>';
      }
    }
  ]
});

// Handle the 'getinvoices' socket event
socket.on('getinvoices', (data) => {
  // Update the table data with the data from the socket event
  table.ajax.reload(null, false);
});
```

You can also specify the data source and other options for the table by passing an object to the ajax.reload() method.

```
table.ajax.reload({
  url: "https://testdma.tech-east.com.pk/dma/invoices/getAllInvoices",
  dataSrc: "doc",
  order: [[0]],
});
```

Comment: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'data'). Getting this error when I am trying to use your code approach @Chuck D

Comment: Although my socket is getting the data in response, but still ajax datatable is considering it as null